# Passing multiple values for a Modelandview

Tags: java, spring, jsp, modelandview

I have a Java Object that I use part of the ModelandView as below,

Spring Controller:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView student() {
      return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
   }
```

Java Object:-

```
import java.util.List;

public class Student {
    private Integer age;
    private String fname;
    private String mname;
    private String lname;
    private String dob;
    private List gender;
    private String birthplace;
    private String nationality;
    private String mothertongue;
    private String religion;
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getMname() {
        return mname;
    }

    public void setMname(String mname) {
        this.mname = mname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public List getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(List gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getBirthplace() {
        return birthplace;
    }

    public void setBirthplace(String birthplace) {
        this.birthplace = birthplace;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public String getMothertongue() {
        return mothertongue;
    }

    public void setMothertongue(String mothertongue) {
        this.mothertongue = mothertongue;
    }

    public String getReligion() {
        return religion;
    }

    public void setReligion(String religion) {
        this.religion = religion;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

JSP file

```
<h2>Student Information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="/SpringMVC/addStudent">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
```

Question:-

I need to pass a list for sex ie; MALE and FEMALE to the JSP File...I can add it as a array in my Java object but how do I reference in my JSP file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring form takes care of it . pass the list from the controller and in jsp ,

```
<form:radiobuttons path="sex" items="${genderList}" />
```

it will populate two radio buttons namely from the `genderList` values. Read the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.radiobutton) here.

Answer (score 0):

How to send mulitple data through modelandview

```java
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        return "first";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/second")
    public ModelAndView second(@RequestParam("firstname") String thename
            ,@RequestParam("lastname") String thelast)
    {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("firstname", thename);
        model.addObject("lastname", thelast);
        model.setViewName("second");
        
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).